# Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7` from ``:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, javascript-debugger

[image]
hello
after I installed redux-thunk I have got this error and I don't know what to do!
I have updated my expo-CLI updated my packages, reset and cleared cache, reset the computer,
before updating my expo-CLI whenever I uninstall the redux-thunk it worked but after updating it won't be solved!

Comment: If you're sure that you have added the library using CLI then try deleting node_modules folder and then type "npm i" command in your CLI